# Why does gradle produce empty archives?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I have a gradle project made of module and submodules.

```
| build.gradle (1)
|- common
    | build.gradle (2)
    |- webutils
        | build.gradle (3)
|- spring
    | build.gradle
    |- security
        | build.gradle
```

This is `build.gradle` (1)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common'), project(':common:webutils')
    compile project(':spring'), project(':spring:security')
}
```

This is `build.gradle` (2)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common:webutils')
}
```

This is `build.gradle` (3)

```
dependencies {
    compile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javaxServletApiVersion}")
    testCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javaxServletApiVersion}")
    testCompile("org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}")
    testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
}
```

When I try to build the jars with `./gradlew clean build` it procdues the following jar :

1. /build/libs/libs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. common/build/libs/common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
3. common/webutils/build/libs/webutils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I expect

- (3) to be include in (2)
- (2), (3) to be include in (1)

Looking at (1)

```
" zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile libs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
~
```

Looking at (2)

```
" zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Looking at (3)

```
" zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile webutils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/domain/
com/domain/api/
com/domain/api/common/
com/domain/api/common/webutils/
com/domain/api/common/webutils/URLUtils.class
com/domain/api/common/webutils/RandomUtils.class
~
```

- Why are my jar (1) and (2) empty ?
- Where are the `compile` and `testCompile` dependencies in (3) not included in the jar ? According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management)

  - `compile`: Compile time dependencies
  - `testCompile`: Additional dependencies for compiling tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't normally bundle jar dependencies inside other jars. What are the contents of your `MANIFEST.MF` files? If you want to bundle the dependencies, you might look at the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

Comment: Thanks @ngreen. I have tried to add the shadow plugin with the configuration provided here:  https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow and I still don't see anything added. Also, I thought that using `compile project(':common:webutils')` actually means that it will "Compile time dependencies".

Comment: This is the content of the `MANIFEST.MF` of an empty jar (there is only one line): `Manifest-Version: 1.0`